# Which blade oil should I use against the Wild Hunt?

Tags: the-witcher-3

The blade oils provide quite a substantial advantage, especially once you can upgrade to the superior versions that do 50% additional damage. But you have to know which oil to use against each foe.

I can't find the Wild Hunt warriors in my bestiary, I've no idea which oil I should use against them and their leaders like Eredin. Which oil is effective against them?

Answer (score 12):

The correct answer was found in the Official Prima Guide - it is Elementa Oil.

Edit: my old link to the forum no longer works. There is a picture from the book in another answer in this thread. I can confirm that it's authentic and correct.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but searching online led me to this. I'm pretty sure other people are looking for answers as well. So here you go. This might help.

[image]

Comment: As best I can tell, the image says Elementa Oil.  If that's the answer, why not just say so?  Why leave it just in the image?  Also, what's the source of the image?  Is it from a website?  Something that comes with the game?  A game guide?  What?

Comment: This image is from the official Prima Guide to Witcher 3. You can actually find the same image in the link I posted in my anwer)

Answer (score 1):

They are specters, so you should use "Specter" oil.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: They are often referenced as "Wraith of the Wild Hunt": http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Hunt

Comment: http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Hunt - This says `The Wild Hunt is a group of specters` (with further references to in-game journals). However, this doesn't confirm that Specter Oil is effective (will test shortly).

Comment: When I fought them, I didn't notice any significant difference in damage between no oil and superior spectre oil. And I suspect that 50% should be pretty obvious bonus. Sadly, my elemental oil was only on basic level, so 10% bonus can be negated by armor and randomness. There is a third option that they have no vulnerability to any oil

Comment: The Wild Hunt Hounds are elementa, so are vulnerable to Elementa Oil. It might be that different Wild Hunt creatures have different weaknesses.

Comment: @Jeeva They may be called Wraith of the Wild Hunt, but a book in the game explains that they are actually Aen Elle Elves. This means that they are not Specters, even though they can teleport. They actually teleport by means of powerful magic.

Answer (score 0):

Elementa oil is used for the Hounds of the Hunt.  I imagine it would be the same for the riders, considering the same elemental design of their armors/weapons. Seems to make a difference in game to me

Answer (score -4):

My best guess would be Hanged Man's Venom because I believe the warriors are elves, which fall into the non-human category. I've been unable to confirm this in-game, however.

Comment: The use of "Best guess" and "I believe" is making this a fairly low quality answer. If you're not sure, you should be able to look the information up, and if needed, provide it as citation.

Comment: this is the correct answer +1

Comment: You can't put Hanged Man's Venom on a silver sword, so it wouldn't work